# Convert to DateTime datatype in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time

How do I convert a pandas column to datetime format?

I have tried this and it did not work.

```
odu1['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(odu1['DateTime'].str.strip(), format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

Here is one example entry of how values in my column look like 06/01/2022 12:00:06 AM

Comment: It works for me without the format string.

Comment: It gives me no error, but when I do odu1['DateTime'].describe()                                                 My dtype of this column is still 'object' and not datetime

Comment: it works for me as posted. What precisely do you mean by "it did not work" ... did not work how? What is the error or the result you think is not correct?

Comment: `.describe()` seems to show it as `object` but `odu1.dtypes` should show it as `datetime64[ns]`.

Comment: I expect it to change for me the datatype of the column to datatime.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? Also what version of pandas are you using? It works fine for me ... not sure what's happening here.

Comment: @JanzaibMBaloch: It is changing the datatype, `.describe()` just shows it as object. From the documentation: "For object data (e.g. strings or timestamps) [...]".

Comment: @sj95126 , you were correct. I should have been checking it by odu1.dtypes --------------